# Did the accent in "without" shift from the first syllable to the second in the past?

Tags: pronunciation, poetry, shakespeare

To be sure, the line from William Shakespeare's *Romeo and Juliet*, written in 1591, reads:

> There is no world with-OUT Verona walls.

However, a passage in John Milton's *Paradise Lost*, written in 1667, i.e. more than seventy years later, runs as follows:

> No light; but rather darkness visible
> Served only to discover sights of woe,
> Regions of sorrow, doleful shades, where peace
> And rest can never dwell, hope never comes
> That comes to all, but torture **WITH-out** end
> Still urges, and a fiery deluge, fed
> With ever-burning sulphur unconsumed.

With the stress on the second syllable, the line would not scan.

Was Shakespeare more colloquial and Milton more conservative? Was WITH-out the *proper* way to pronounce the word in those days?

And by *proper* I mean commonly accepted by the grammar Nazis of the day.

Comment: Or did one of Shakespeare or Milton put the stress on an off-beat syllable in these lines? Or was *without* accented on the second syllable when it mean *outside* and on the first syllable when it meant *lacking*?

Comment: Not all lines of either Milton or Shakespeare scan in perfect iambic pentameter. But you seem to have noticed something real: Shakespeare almost always accents the second syllable, while Milton seems uncertain which syllable to accent. Consider these lines: "Cast out from God and blessed vision, falls // Ordained without redemption, without end.”

Comment: @peterShor: 1. Intriguing. Definitely worth looking into.2. Shakespeare often deliberately switches to trochaic and back in order to avoid monotony. ... "without redemption, without end" - Yeah, that's a puzzler.

Comment: Note that the two quotes are using the word in two entirely different senses.  There are modern English words whose syllable stress varies based on local meaning.

Comment: @HotLicks: Not entirely.

Answer (score 5):

> With the stress on the second syllable, the line would not scan.

Herein lies the problem. Milton's "blank verse" is *notoriously* irregular, so much so that whole careers have been spent trying to elucidate the precise rules underlying its metrical structure. Indeed, an important part of Milton's poetic legacy was his challenge to the very idea of a metrical "foot" as the fundamental unit of rhythm. This is a fascinating topic but, alas, much too complicated to get in to here. (If you're interested, I would suggest [this essay](https://www.jstor.org/stable/4501598) by John Creaser as an excellent entree to the subtleties of Milton's prosody.) Suffice it to say that one should exercise extreme caution when attempting to make inferences about historical pronunciation from considerations of scansion in Milton. For instance, in the passage you quoted from Book I of *Paradise Lost*, interpreting the third line as a strict iambic pentameter would yield:

```
 x  /   x   /  x    /   x    /       x    / 
Regions of sorrow, doleful shades, where peace
```

Should we therefore, in reading this line, pronounce the first word as re-GIONS? No! As Robert Bridges [wrote](https://archive.org/details/miltonsprosodywi00brid/page/34/mode/2up) in his seminal 1889 study *Milton's Prosody*:

> The intended rhythm in P.L. is always given by the unmitigated
> accentuation of the words of the verse as Milton pronounced them; nor
> does the qualification 'as he pronounced them' raise much uncertainty.

As a matter of terminology, the use of "Regions" in the line quoted above would traditionally be called *inversion* (i.e., the substitution of a trochee for an "expected" iamb). Yet, if one [examines](https://www.dartmouth.edu/%7Emilton/reading_room/pl/book_1/text.shtml) the first few hundred lines of *Paradise Lost*, one will find only a handful that scan exactly as "expected" without violence. Indeed, one can easily find far more radical deviations from the iambic "ideal." By way of example, Bridges offers the following line from Book III:

```
  /       /       /      /           /
Shoots invisible virtue even to the deep.
```

According to Bridges, we should read this as "SHOOTS in-VIS-ible VIR-tue EVen to the DEEP," which is both intuitively reasonable and clearly not iambic pentameter. I will refrain from discussing Bridges's actual theory of scansion, as it is irrelevant (and somewhat controvertial). However, the basic point about pronunciation is absolutely spot on: one must never torture Milton's verse into bizarre patterns of word stress just to bring it in line with some imagined ideal of iambic pentameter---let alone interpret its noncompliance with that imagined ideal as evidence of an actual difference in pronunciation.

At the risk of beating a dead horse, it is worth consulting some early modern sources to test our suspicions about the pronunciation of *without*. Shakespeare, as you have already pointed out, usually places the word so that its second syllable coincides with the ictus of a putative iamb (though even he will depart from this pattern when it suits him):

> 'Tide life, 'tide death, I come **without** delay.
> (*A Midsummer Night's Dream*, 5.1.2047)

> O villains, vipers, damn'd **without** redemption!
> (*Richard II*, 3.2.1539)

but

> As, by my faith, I see no more in you
> Than **without** candle may go dark to bed
> (*As You Like It*, 3.5.1691-92)

> And all the number of his fair demands
> Shall be accomplish'd **without** contradiction.
> (Richard III, 3.3.1764-65)

And [here](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Spelling_Dictionary_Or_a_Collection/zVBgAAAAcAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA177) is the entry for *without* in Thomas Dyche's *Spelling Dictionary* of 1723, the first such dictionary to indicate word stress (via accent marks):

[image: Dyche's entry for "without" showing the usual iambic stress]

Of course, Milton had already died some 49 years before this work was published (and Shakespeare some 58 years before that!), but this does at least establish that any hypothetical fad in the pronunciation of *without* would have to have died off before the 1720s. Surely the parsimonious explanation is that there was no such fad.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply. I'd scan the line you and Bridges quote as "Shoots IN-vis-IB-[u]l VIR-tue E'En t' the DEEP," but that's a whole different matter, I suppose. The iamb-trochee switch at the beginning of a line ("Regions") was a common practice in that epoch, I think. But thank you again for giving me a great deal to think about. Great stuff!

Comment: You're absolutely right that the first position is a particularly common spot for inversion, not just in Milton. But what *is* unique to Milton is the pervasive willingness to run roughshod over metrical conventions governing the distribution of stresses in a line of verse. There's another interesting example from Book III which I almost mentioned: "So without least impulse or shadow of fate." I think it must be "SO withOUT least IMpulse or SHAdow of FATE," whereas a naive scansion might yield "so WITHout LEAST imPULSE ..."

Comment: I beg to differ, it should be "so WITH-out LEAST im-PULSE or SHA-dowf FATE," the second syllable of the "shadow" and "of" merging, because "w" is a semi-vowel," or some such nonsense. Milton was, after all, unlike most poets, a perfect nerd. His talent transcended his nerdiness, of that there is no doubt in my mind, at least. I remember studying a rhyming poem of his in college whose title escapes me right now in which he added a "y" to the beginning of a word so that the line would scan. Any other self-respecting English poet would have sooner moved to France (Oscar Wilde was Irish).

Comment: Oh, yes: im-PULSE. If there's a pulse, there ought to be an im-PULSE as well. Why not.

Comment: My point, as with the "shoots invisible virtue" example above, is simply that it should give one pause if the obvious scansion seems to imply very unnatural pronunciations such as "IN-vis-IBle" or "imPULSE," which is just not the way anyone ever says those words. In the latter case, it's also particularly telling, I think, that a ditrochaic "SO withOUT least" sets up a double dactylic "IMpulse or SHAdow of FATE" while simultaneously reproducing the natural word stresses. That strikes me as a much better outcome than what results from forcing it into an iambic structure.

Comment: Also, it is almost universally accepted at this point that Milton was quite experimental in his metrical approach to blank verse. To suppose that a poet of his originality would be bound by convention to the iambic da-DUM da-DUM da-DUM does not give him enough credit, I think. (I realize this might seem rather circular reasoning, but I think his originality is plain to see in many other areas besides prosody.)

Comment: Don't underestimate circular reasoning. It's known to work wonders sometimes. As is the "no true Scotsman" argument.

Comment: But Shakespeare was 70 years before Milton; you really should be looking at Milton's contemporaries to find the pronunciation of *without*. Alexander Pope seems to be much closer to Milton than Shakespeare in his pronunciation of *without*  — for example, "Such, without wit, are Poets when they please, //
As without learning they can take Degrees." And I think Pope wrote much stricter iambic pentameter than Milton.

Comment: @Ricky: Is there any evidence at all that anybody pronounced *invisible* any way other than *inVISible*. Shakespeare accented the second syllable: *Then shall you know the wounds invisible // That love's keen arrows make.* John Donne accented the second syllable: *Things invisible to see,* Alexander Pope accented the second syllable: *Abrupt, with eagle-speed she cut the sky; //
Instant invisible to mortal eye.* In that line, Milton is deviating from perfect iambic pentameter.

Comment: You can't tell anything about pronunciations from a single instance of a word in one poem. The right way to approach this is to take a bunch of poets between the late 16th and early 18th centuries, and compile statistics on how often they used *without* in odd and even positions. Just from spot-checking Shakespeare's, Milton's, and Pope's poems, my guess is that you'd see a significant change. But this is much too time-consuming a task for me to undertake.

Comment: @PeterShor: So, you're saying, it was with-OUT at first (as in most of Shakespeare), and then it changed to WITH-out, and then, eventually, it changed back. It's an intriguing theory. Perhaps scholarly authors came up with, and insisted on, the first syllable, but later on the vernacular version won out.

Comment: @Ricky: I'm saying it was *withOUT* when Shakespeare wrote. But when Milton and Pope wrote, the accent on instances of *without* seems roughly evenly distributed between the first and second syllables (so either there were two acceptable pronunciations or it had a reasonably strong accent on both syllables). And now it's changed back.

Comment: @PeterShor That's what _I_ was saying too.

Comment: @PeterShor I fully expect that you *would* find a difference between, say, 1600s and 1660s, but I would be more inclined (a priori) to attribute that to an increase in literary experimentation and willingness to flout the metrical conventions of Shakespearean blank verse. If one were going to test this rigorously, I think it would be key to establish a corpus of texts that cleave demonstrably to a strict iambic framework (i.e., not Milton). Otherwise one runs the risk of conflating evolution or relaxation of the metrical conventions themselves with change in the underlying pronunciation.

Comment: @SoupyTwist: I checked a different preposition: All the instances of *beyond* I checked in Shakespeare and Pope were placed consistently with the second syllable being accented in strict iambic pentameter, and I checked enough to be reasonably sure that Pope treats *without* differently than *beyond*. As I said, I don't have time to test this rigorously, but I really think there's something interesting going on with *without*.

Comment: @PeterShor That's an interesting observation. It may well be that *without* had some special characteristic that lent itself to being placed more flexibly in verse (or vice versa for *beyond*). Still, that in and of itself does not necessarily entail a difference in pronunciation (as opposed to placement) within a poetic context, much less in the context of everyday life. That said, if you're right about *beyond*, I do think that lends credence to the idea that something more than meter might be at play here.